# Вынесение констант actions в отдельный файл

Tags: javascript, vue.js, архитектура, vuex

Разбираю тему модульности в vuex на примере приложения с аутентификацией ([статья](https://blog.sqreen.io/authentication-best-practices-vue/), [репозиторий на гитхабе](https://github.com/sqreen/vue-authentication-example)), переписываю с нуля по-своему, сравниваю полученный код. Возник вопрос.

Когда я создавал модуль auth то закинул всё относящееся к этому модулю в файл `\store\modules\auth.js`

Когда я начал сравнивать с кодом приложения - увидел, что в нём разделено на два файла: один как у меня, а второй — `\store\actions\auth.js`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нём только определено несколько констант:

```
export const AUTH_REQUEST = 'AUTH_REQUEST'
export const AUTH_SUCCESS = 'AUTH_SUCCESS'
export const AUTH_ERROR = 'AUTH_ERROR'
export const AUTH_LOGOUT = 'AUTH_LOGOUT'
```

Вот мне непонятно, что даёт такое разбиение на два файла в плане структуры приложения? В статье этот момент не описывается, видимо подразумевается, как очевидный. В [офдоке](https://vuex.vuejs.org/ru/guide/modules.html) же такой приём не используется.

У меня самого два предположения:

- Вероятно, это как-то может упрощать рефакторинг наименований методов (не уверен, но вообще-то это задача IDE и по идее vscode должна уметь нормально обрабатывать подобные ситуации - когда я в visual code + resharper переименовываю метод, то никаких дополнительных подсказок IDE не нужно)
- Это так явно вынесено описание возможных переходов между состояниями конечного автомата (тоже не уверен: тогда логичнее было бы использовать enum)

Понимаю, что в вопросе есть некоторая толика неоднозначности ("перефразируйте вопрос чтобы можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ"), но возможно, что это какой-то конкретный типовой ход, который широко используется и я просто ещё не сталкивался.